# How can I stop ResourceManager from defaulting to my current culture if a key is not found

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, localization, resx

The question is pretty self-explanatory, but here's a sample reproduction case.

I have three resx files:

```
Translations.resx
  Has code generation enabled and no key-value pairs
```

---

```
Translations.en.resx
  String1 : Value1
  String2 : Value2
```

---

```
Translations.fr.resx
  String1 : Valeur1
```

To obtain a resource from the french resource I can call:

```
Translations.ResourceManager.GetString("String1", new CultureInfo("fr"));
```

This returns `Valeur1` as expected. Changing the parameter to `String2` returns `Value2` which follows the [resource fallback process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618.aspx#cpconpackagingdeployingresourcesanchor1).

What I would like to do is shut off this process and allow a null to be returned if the key is not in the specific culture I provided to `GetKey`. Is it possible and if so how do I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think you can. I suspect the best you can do is to have an empty string (say) as the default resource and provide a proper string for each language you support in separate `.fr.resx`, `.de.resx`, `en.resx`, etc. files.